# How to use selected value of filter box in Apache Superset?

Tags: html, markdown, apache-superset

I'm using Apache Superset to show analysis result dashboard. and I want to read the imagefile(.png) from a particular path and show it to users.

The Superset dashboard shows different results depending on 'guid', and I also want to show different image depending on 'guid'.

This 'guid' value can only be selected by filter box. (This filter box is linked to a table in the DB.)

Markdown is used as a way to show images. Also I want to use 'guid' value in image file path.
For example,

1. if the 'guid' value selected in the filter box is '1q2w3e4r',
2. at Markdown --> ![image](/superset/result/1q2w3e4r/result.png)
3. result.png will be shown in Markdown region.
   As above, 'guid' enters the folder name on the path and shows the image file('result.png')

Can I show the image while dynamically changing the 'guid' value according to the filter box's selection as above?

My Superset version is 2.0.1.
If there's any other way possible, it doesn't have to be Markdown.